# How can I use an analog switch to control a higher voltage than vcc?

Tags: arduino, voltage, integrated-circuit, switching

I am using an Arduino and several analog switches (TEXAS INSTRUMENTS CD74HC4066E) to control several items (LEDs and other devices.)  The switching voltage that comes out of the Arduino is 5v, but several of the voltages that I need to switch are higher (typically 9 volts for LED strips.)

Will these analog switches be able to control 9 volts if 5 volts is used to switch it?

Should VCC be 5 volts or 9 volts?

is 12 volts and option?

Comment: what does the datasheet say?

Comment: It says a lot, in language that I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is "No". If you want to switch 9 volts, the CD74HC4066E can do it, but Vcc must be 9 volts. If you look at Figure 1 (Typical "ON" resistance vs input signal range) you'll see that the input is essentially limited to Vcc, so a Vcc can handle 0 - 4.5, and Vcc can handle - 9. In this case, Vih (input "HIGH" voltage) must be a minimum of about 6 volts, and this is more than your Arduino can provide.

There are a number of alternatives available. First, you can get a level shifter. For instance, an [MC14504](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwjE7Nzi7N7HAhWMjQ0KHWs-AkM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thierry-lequeu.fr%2Fdata%2FMC14504.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHWsGbd601UshO-LxfYV6vQphcrWw&sig2=3Z_PK4pIr2e7lQbBoPDQZQ) will do what you want, assuming you don't need to provide more than about 2 mA of current.

If you want more current, there are other level shifters available, or you can use a MOSFET driver chip. I'm personally partial to the Maxim [MAX4426 - MAX4428](https://www.schukat.com/schukat/pdf.nsf/index/A4D8D51A0A7886C2C12571B80042292C/$file/MAX4426-MAX4428.pdf) series, but that's just because I've used them before and am lazy.

Finally, of course, you can roll your own using a transistor or 2. Depending on how much current you need to source or sink you can try either of

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffW3cR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

these circuits.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of varieties of the basic 4066 design, none of which seem to be called 4hc4066e. You should however not assume that you can use these circuits to switch any higher voltage than the circuit's supply voltage.

If you are simply using Arduino's GPIO pins to switch things on and off, using a 4066 circuit is nevertheless quite an overkill. You can also use the GPIO output to drive an NPN or FET transistor. The schematics on [this page](http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits) (output circuits 'using an NPN transistor' or 'using a FET') can also be used with the Arduino, although the page is targeted at Raspberry PI users. Both circuits are capabable of switching higher voltages than the output of the GPIO pin.

Comment: overkill in what way?

Comment: The 4066 is a bidirectional analouge switch and if you are only switching e.g. a LED on and off, you neither need a bidirectional, nor an analogue switch. Except for being unnecessary expensive, that won't mean that it can't switch unidirectional, digital signals. But as you've discovered, you must accept a limited switching voltage and relatively low switching currents.

Comment: @tcrosley As you can see, the OP edited his question after my answer and entered the correct part number. Since all the 4066 variants have different electrical characteristics, the exact part number could be important to answer his question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get analogue switches that have a seperate "switch" supply to the logic supply. The "switch" supply can be in the order of several tens of volts whilst the logic supply to the device can remain at 3V3 or 5V. Do some hunting at MAXIM, ADI or TI.

In fact you can get analogue switches that just use the switch supply and have 2V logic levels that are compatible with 3V3 systems and 5V systems.

Comment: Is there a specific name for these kind of switches?

Comment: They are still analogue switches so this isn't useful for googling. Just try searching the sources. Try MAXIM first because, from memory, they have something called "beyond-the-rails analogue switches. Don't hang me on that one.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a device called a photovoltaic stack .This gives you the same isolation as an optocoupler .You dont have to worry about supply voltages now .The input of the photovoltaic stack looks electricaly like a normal garden variety optocoupler so its easy to drive.The isolated output is about 5Vdc which is fine for driving a logic level N channel mosfet.If this sounds OK then check for snags on www.badbeetles.com and get some photovoltaic stacks.IR used to and may still make them.